# Retrieve POST-data from view in controller

Tags: php, forms, post

I'm trying to do something very basic: retrieve a post value from a hidden field. The hidden field is obviously in my view file and I want to retrieve the value in my controller. I'm using the framework SimpleMVCFramework.

I have a hidden field in my `projects.php` file (the list with projects). When you click on a project, a method in the controller renders the clicked project and the corresponding page. This corresponding page is called `project.php`

The hidden field in my `projects.php` view:

```
<form method="post" action="project.php">
     <input type="hidden" name="project-id" value="<?php echo $project['id'];?>">
</form>
```

This hidden form is displayed correctly in my lists with projects. I checked them in the console.

In my ProjectController.php, I try to retrieve the data using

```
$data['id'] = $_POST['project-id'];
```

Then, I send the `$data` variable with the rendered page, so that I can use the `id`. So every project in `projects.php` has a hidden file that outputs correctly. When I try and click on a project, it brings me to `project.php`, but when I check out the `$data` variable, the `id` is just empty.

The routing works like a charm, because e.g. `$data['title'] = "Project";` works great and is visible when I check the `$data` variable. When I change

```
$data['id'] = $_POST['project-id'];
```

to

```
$data['id'] = "foobar";
```

the `id` in `project.php` isn't empty anymore, but shows `foobar`. So I guess that something goes wrong with retrieving the value.

I also tried to remove the `action=".."` from the form, but that also didn't work.

The thing I'm trying to achieve is so simple, that I don't understand what is going wrong. Is it possible that the problem lies with the framework and that the code is right?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: So, you click a project name in a projects.php generated list and get into project.php where some data is missing? I am guessing you are actually clicking a link instead submitting a form, therefore your $_POST[] is empty on project.php. Please submit more of your code, as this is just a guess now.

Comment: User input should be handled in the controllers. But It should be abstracted (for example as a `Request` class instance). Using superglobals *deep inside* your code is considered to be a bad practice.